# Rider "extern alias" and "using" support

Tags: c#, .net, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have some kind of a `References` DLL that contains references etc for, for instance, Newtonsoft.Json. I add it to project, use `extern alias References` and `using References::Newtonsoft.Json`, but Rider doesn't like it:

[image: Screenshot from JetBrains Rider]

P.S. *It works absolutely fine in Visual Studio.*

Comment: can you review my answer and see if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: this has been fixed as of version 2019.3

If you're using an older version the workaround is to create a file in the root project folder called {solutionName}.sln.DotSettings with this data:

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<s:String x:Key="/Default/Environment/Hierarchy/Build/BuildTool/MsBuildSolutionLoadingTargets/@EntryValue">ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies</s:String></wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

As found here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-476048

Comment: I can't get this feature working in 2022.1.1